# I'm unable to log into django app with other accounts except the superuser

Tags: python, django, multiple-users

I am new to Django.
I have a project where I'm not able to log in with other  accounts except the superuser account.
Here are my models

```
class School(models.Model):
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False,default='school')

class User(AbstractUser):
    schools = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False,default=1)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)


class Student(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    adm = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
```

I am new to Django and self learning. May anybody out there help me, please.
Where could the problem be??

My LOGIN VIEW.

```
def Login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            if username.endswith("@teacher"):
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return redirect('students')
            #return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'Invalid Credentials')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        return render(request, 'login2.html')

    return redirect('teachers')
```

User Creation Forms

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_teacher = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
            school = School.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_student = True
        user.save()
        student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
        #student.interests.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('interests'))
        return user
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? I think at least settings.py, urls.py and a basic views example would help a lot. Other than this, My advice would be to check this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: We need to see the `login.html` and `login` views function as well.

Comment: can i see your usercreation form